# Solving equation system with linear combination of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, matrix-equations

I do have an equation system of the form:
$$\vec M = a \cdot
\mathrm{diag}\left(c_1, c_2, c_3. c_4, c_5\right)
\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}x^{-2}\\ x^{-1}\\1\\x\\x^2\end{matrix}\right)
+b\cdot
\mathrm{diag}\left(d_1, d_2, d_3, d_4, d_5\right)
\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}y^{-2}\\ y^{-1}\\ 1\\ y\\ y^2 \end{matrix}\right)$$

I want to obtain $x$ and $y$.

$a$ and $b$ are unknown but need not be determined. $\vec M \in \mathbb{R}^5$ is known as well as $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $d_i \in \mathbb{R}$ with $i \in \{1,2,\dots,5\}$. 
$\mathrm{diag}(c_i)$ denotes a symmetric diagonal matrix with diagonal coeffcients $c_i$.

The equation systems seem to be generic enough so that I suppose someone has already investigated it. Any clues where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How can $M$ be a vector if the right side is scalar?  The row-column-vector products give scalar results, nothing 5-dimensional.

Comment: You are right @LutzL , I corrected the question.

Comment: As you only have 4 free parameters/variables, generically you can only satisfy 4 of the 5 equations.

Comment: ok, the third equation is the least important equation. If I want to solve the other equations (1,2,4,5), where would I start?

Comment: Any CAS that actually does (abstract) algebra, that is, not Matlab & co. By the Bezout bound, you can have up to $4\cdot 2\cdot2\cdot3=48$ solutions over the complex numbers, due to the structure of the equations a number of them may lie at infinity.